# Cannot connect Rockchip 3066 device to adb on mac os

Tags: android, macos, adb

I am trying to connect my Rockchip 3066 (momo7) device to adb on Mac OS X. But I see nothing on

```
adb devices
```

List is empty.
There are solutions for Windows - alternative adb.exe, but I didn't find one for Mac.
I tried add vendor ID 0x2207 to adb_usb.ini but no success.
Any suggestions how to make it work, please.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add the number to adb_usb.ini as 0x2207.  Don't forget the 0x, and do not have any empty lines.  Yes, it's that picky.  "adb start-server" should report "* daemon started successfully *".  In event of failure it will say "ADB server didn't ACK, * failed to start daemon *".

Answer (score 1):

The instructions below worked for me for connecting my macbook air to a rockchip rk3188 stick computer. Additional things to check are:

i) Settings -> Developer options -> USB debugging [need to be checked]

ii) Settings -> USB -> Connect to PC [need to be checked]

```
$> sudo nano ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

Add the following line

Code:

0x2207

Restart the adb server

Code:

$> sudo adb kill-server

Code:

$> sudo adb start-server

Now Rockchip device will show up

Code:

$> adb devices
List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF    device
```

Referred from:

http://forum.yarvik.com/forum/xenta-series/yarvik-xenta-general-discussion/1916-device-not-listed-using-android-adb-tool

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't think this will work, because the SDK Tools were updated many times since 28-09-2012 (the date is the post date from the link above). Anyway, I'll try this.

Comment: vendor id list can be found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/usb_vendors.c

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same on several Windows machines and on a Mac with another, also very much cheap Chineese but nice device. It turns out that the main problem is in adp. If the device is listed in a device manager or system report and displays the "connected for debugging" notification, then it is recognized and there are no driver related problems. This is easy to acheive on both Mac and Windows.

However, "adb devices" does not show the device. In Windows, I just followed an advice from the Net and used adb version .26 and it worked.

The lack of support for Rockchip is evidently intentional. I do not know who maintains adb, but if it is Google et. allies, then they just do not like cheap devices.

Comment: There's no intentional slight - the support for adding devices whose VIDs aren't recognized out of the box is there, and it works.